# Make qmake not append .so

Tags: qt, shared-libraries, qmake

Is there some way to modify qmake project files (*.pro) such that qmake doesn't append .so when building shared library files? I know it happens because of the target file type...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding something like this to your .pro file:

```
QMAKE_EXTENSION_SHLIB = some_other_extension
```

Comment: Was hoping to find something that would stop it from appending any suffix, but this will work for now and will lead me in the right direction.